# Approach to automatically upload updated assets to ftp

Tags: ftp, automation

Say I need to track about 10 big files (each over 1G) over the the LAN shared folder, and if the files get modified/updated/overwritten, I need to upload those new files to ftp, and do some sort of notification like email.

But I don't need to version control for older files, so it won't inflate the repository.

How could be an easy approach to this? Since it need to keep monitoring the files, ftp protocol, email notification. Will make a C# program be a feasible way to do this? Or any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT:

After checking around a couple version control large binaries threads in SO, it seems I don't need a version control system. Actually, I just need to keep checking the file metadata and once it's changed, upload to ftp and send out email. Not sure Mogware can disable backup old binaries?

Is there any other tools are feasible for this specific case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm in no way affiliated with the guys at Mogware, but there is a tool called "FileHamster" which is a personal revision tool, offering you to track file changes, call scripts after a file has changed etc. It also provides FTP upload.